# Confused about command prompt, Visual Studio exe's and text files?

Tags: c, visual-studio, cmd

The title doesn't really do this topic justice. It's actually quite simple, my problem that is. I have a program (code below) written in the C language. I want this program to create an exe file that can be ran through the command prompt console window and that will also take a text file as a parameter. So, long story short; I need it to say this on the command line in CMD:

C:\Users\Username\Desktop\wrapfile.exe content.txt

My only problem is getting the code right. I want to tell Visual Studio: "The file you should open is given in the command prompt window as a parameter, there is no set location..."

How do I do that?

Here is my working code (Although you will have to change a few things in the *fp definition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *fp; // declaring variable 


    fp = fopen("c:\\users\\*Put you're PC username here*\\Desktop\\contents.txt", "rb"); // opens the file


    if (fp != NULL) // checks the return value from fopen
    {
        int i;
        do
        {
            i = fgetc(fp);     // scans the file 
            printf("%c",i);
            printf(" ");
        }
        while(i!=-1);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error.\n");
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You should investigate what `argc` and `argv[]` are in the parameters to `main`. Here's a hint: One is the number of **command line parameters** that are contained in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ken said above, the arguments of the main method are the values that you pass in from the command line. Argc is 'argument count' and argv is 'argument values'. So to open the fist argument passed in from the command line, change

```
fp = fopen("c:\\users\\*Put you're PC username here*\\Desktop\\contents.txt", "rb"); // opens the file
```

to

```
fp = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
```

Just make sure to do error checking (ie argv[1] is not null) before you try to fopen the input. Also FYI, in your case argv[0] will be the name of your executable.

Comment: I tried changing the fp declaration to the one you provided, however, I seemed to get an error saying: "Too few argument in function call" The last round bracket is also underlined. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry :) forgot to include the mode when I posted my original answer, see my modifications.

Comment: also, if an answer on here works for you, please mark it as the solution? Everyone appreciates more reputation!

Comment: Yup, I accepted it as an answer. I'm new to stackoverflow, so if there is something else I can do to say thank you, just let me know :D 

You, sir have put a smile on my face!! :D

Comment: @JamesHeartly when it comes to questions, accepting a solution gives the solution's poster reputation, and it also helps your 'percent accepted' statistic. The better the 'percent accepted' statistic of a question's poster, the more likely people are to answer the question. I'm still pretty new here too, but like me I'm sure you'll get the hang of it quick!