# How would I get more then one text file accepted?

Tags: c, file, text, cmd

Right now, I have something like this...

CMD console window:
c:\users\username\Desktop> wrapfile.txt hello.txt

Hello

How would I get something like this?

CMD console window:
c:\users\username\Desktop> wrapfile.txt hello.txt hi.txt

Hello Hi

with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc[1], char *argv[1])
{
    FILE *fp; // declaring variable 
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (fp != NULL) // checks the return value from fopen
    {
        int i;
        do
        {
            i = fgetc(fp);     // scans the file 
            printf("%c",i);
            printf(" ");
        }
        while(i!=-1);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You asked a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13734843/62576) before, and were given the information about how to solve this one (remember `argc` and `argv[]`?). Are you even *reading* the answers you're getting, or are you just copying and pasting the code? (And your definition of `main(argc[1], argv[1])` is wrong; `argc` and `argv[]` are passed in to you, with `argc` containing the number of items you'll find in `argv[]`; you don't declare them with pre-defined sizes - you'd know that if you **read** the answers you got).

Comment: I'm reading them, but Ken, I'm new to C and I'm trying to learn. I don't copy and paste the code, I read it over and if I understand it, I write a similar code that works, if I don't, I google it and see how it works.

Comment: The `argc` and `argv[]` were both mentioned (first by me in a comment, and then in the answer you accepted). Both of them mention what `argc` and `argv[]` are and how they're used, but you ignored it in this question posted less than a day later. The accepted answer even demonstrates how to use the `argv[]` array by retrieving the first element from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all: in your `main` declaration, you should use `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` instead of what you have right now. Specifying an array size makes no sense when declaring an `extern` variable (that's what argv and argc are). On the top of that, you are not using the correct types. `argc` is `integer` and `argv` is `array of strings` (which are `arrays of chars`). So `argv` is an array of arrays of `char`s.

Then, simply use the argc counter to loop through the argv array. `argv[0]` is the name of the program, and `argv[1]` to `argv[n]` will be the arguments you pass to your program while executing it.

Here is a good explanation on how this works: http://www.physics.drexel.edu/courses/Comp_Phys/General/C_basics/#command-line

My 2 cents.

---

EDIT: Here is a commented version of the working program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    if(argc < 3)    // Check that you can safely access to argv[0], argv[1] and argv[2].
    {               // If not, (i.e. if argc is 1 or 2), print usage on stderr.
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file> <file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;   // Then exit.
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");   // Open the first file.
    if (fp == NULL)   // Check for errors.
    {
        printf("Error: cannot open file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    do   // Read it.
    {
        c = fgetc(fp); // scans the file
        if(c != -1)
            printf("%c", c);
    } while(c != -1);
    fclose(fp);   // Close it.

    fp = fopen(argv[2], "rb");   // Open the second file.
    if (fp == NULL)   // Check for errors.
    {
        printf("Error: cannot open file %s\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    do   // Read it.
    {
        c = fgetc(fp); // scans the file
        if(c != -1)
            printf("%c", c);
    } while(c!=-1);
    fclose(fp);   // Close it.

    return 0;       // You use int main and not void main, so you MUST return a value.
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I did read over it, and it did help me understand what I'm doing, but it doesn't help me understand why my program keeps crashing lol

http://pastebin.com/L0RqjYYM

Comment: If you have more than two files to read, since the operations to do are repetitive, and the data structures (file descriptor, and else) are re-usable, you can put the file opening and reading (and closing) in a loop structure (for, or while).

Answer (score 1):

argv[2] would be the second file name.

Do not forget to check the value of argc to see if enough arguments are valid.

Better: use boost::program_options.

Caution: this code is not unicode-aware on Windows system, which makes it not portable. Refer to utf8everywhere.org about how to make it support all file names on this platform.

Comment: And if I wanted more then two .txt files, how would that work? I know your answer works, and thank you, but if I wanted to have an unlimited number of text files, would that be possible as well?

Comment: yes. argv[as big natural number as you like]. Still, do not write like this. Submarine onion peeling is a punishment for unicode-broken code.

Comment: lol alright. I'll do some research on the argc and argv commands in C. I'll go from there, thanks again :)

Comment: Hey Pavel, I had a quick question. I tried changing the argv values to 3 (assuming it would accept 3 text files) and it crashed on me. I changed both argv values to 3, so it would look like this: 

int main(int argc[1], char *argv[3])

and 

fp = fopen(argv[3], "rb");

Comment: main should look like this: int main(int argc, char **argv).

Comment: Oh, it's getting closer. I tried changing out main to int main(int argc, char **argv) and fp = fopen(argv[3], "rb"); remained the same, and now I can access the third file I put through on the command line. So it's like this: 

CMD console window:
c:\users\username\Desktop> wrapfile.txt hello.txt how.txt are.txt

are

If I do this:

CMD console window:
c:\users\username\Desktop> wrapfile.txt hello.txt how.txt

The program crashes. 

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: try commenting out parts to see why it crashes.